# how do i find the distance between a vector and a line or plane

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Lets say I have a vector Y (1,2,3) and a line spanned by the vector V (4,5,6). How would i find the distance between Y and V? What if V was spanned by two or more vectors? Edit: I've added the actual question, don't understand how it ends up being 3.

Comment: What do you call the distance between two vectors?

Comment: is it the magnitude?

Comment: I know what is the distance between a *point* and a line, or a plane, but not between a vector and a line.

Comment: what would it be

Comment: No idea, except if in the context what is denoted as vectors are really points in $3$-space.

Answer (score 1):

**How it ends up being three** :

The first is a 2-D problem so it should be very easy to visualise. I encourage you to draw a diagram first and it'll all be clear.

The line spanned by $\vec v = (1,0)$ is the $x-$axis in the standard cartesian coordinate system. The vector $\vec y = (2,3)$ starts at the origin and ends at the point $(2,3)$.

Now, the definition of *distance*, in this case, treating $y$ as a point, is the shortest distance from the point to the line. What is the *shortest distance*? It is indeed the perpendicular one.  Therefore, you need to find the perpendicular distance from the point $(2,3)$ to the $x$ axis. Can you now see why it is $3$? (i.e Think about the length of $AD$ in the diagram below).

[image]

As for the second question, here's a hint.
In general, the distance in Euclidean space between two **vectors** $ \vec u = \left< u_1, \cdots , u_n \right>$ and $\vec v = \left< v_1, \cdots , v_n \right>$ is given by$$d(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) = \| \vec{u} - \vec{v} \| = \sqrt{(u_1 - v_1)^2 + (u_2 - v_2)^2 ... (u_n - v_n)^2}$$

The distance between a point $P$ in space and the line $L$ pwith parametric equation $r(\vec t) = \vec {OQ} + t\vec u$ is given by $$d(P,L) = \frac{| \vec {PQ} \times \vec u|}{|\vec u|}$$

I've presented both formulas because the question is phrased unconventionally, at least for me. If you have to find the distance between the line spanned by the vector $\vec v = (4,5,6)$ and the vector $\vec u = (1,2,3)$, then you'd have to take $\vec u$ as a position vector. That means, in the context of the problem, you can treat it as the point $P$ from the formula.

Next, you'll have to find the equation, preferably in parametric form, of the line spanning $\vec v$. To do that, you can simply take $(4,5,6)$ as the **point** $Q$ on the line. Subract the $0$ vector to get $\vec {OQ}$. Then take any non-zero multiple of the **vector** $\vec v = (4,5,6)$ and that'll be your direction vector $\vec u$. That is enough information to come up with the parametric equation of the line.

After that, you'll have all the information you need to use the formula for the distance between a line and a point in space.

Comment: yes that helped alot

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intuition here is that we can travel to the point associated with $\vec{y}$ by first moving parallel to the line associated with $\vec{v}$ and then "turning" and travelling towards $\vec{y}$ in a straight line. The shortest path will have us turning exactly 90 degrees. We can compute how far we travelled parallel to $\vec{v}$ by leveraging the net distance that we travelled or what coordinates we ended up at.

The minimum Euclidean distance between (the point specified by) a vector $\vec{y}$ and a line passing through the origin parameterized by the non-zero vector $\vec{v}$ is (101) or (102):

$$ \sqrt{\left\lVert \vec{y} \right\rVert^2 - \frac{(\vec{y} \cdot \vec{v})^2}{\left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert^2}} \tag{101} $$

or

$$ \left\lVert \vec{y} - \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{y}}{\lVert \vec{v} \rVert} \right\rVert \tag{102} $$

We can think of a line as the collection of points associated with scalar multiples of the designated vector $\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix} 
$.

We have a right triangle consisting of the following: We have a vector $\vec{v}$ and its distance from the origin is $\lVert\vec{v}\rVert$, which corresponds to the hypotenuse of the triangle. We also know that the geometric interpretation of the dot product of a vector $\vec{a}$ and a unit vector $\vec{u}$ is how much $\vec{a}$ points in the direction of $\vec{u}$.

The second term $(\vec{y}\cdot\vec{v})\;/\; (\lVert\vec{v}\rVert)$, then, is how much $y$ points in the direction of $v$.

In the ASCII art diagram below, we can see that we can do the arithmetic two ways. We can proceed by first "subtracting off" how much $\vec{y}$ points in the direction of $\vec{v}$ and then measuring the length of the vector normal to the line spanned by $\vec{v}$ (102). We can also use the pythagorean theorem and get the separation between $\vec{y}$ and the line spanned by $\vec{v}$ that way.

```
    (102)    y
        |   /|
        |  / |
        | /  |
        |/   |
        /    |
        ------line-spanned-by-v-----
```

One way to visualize (102) is to imagine "backtracking" parallel to the line spanned by $\vec{v}$ after reaching $\vec{y}$ until we're normal to $v$.

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} - \alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} $$

at which point the length is obvious.

Comment: how would you compute it with the pythagorean theorem

Comment: The squared-magnitude of $v$ is $9+4$, the $(v \cdot y)^2$ is $4$. And then $\sqrt{9 + 4 - 4 } = 3$.